# Rails nested resources for all members of an outer resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a routes file like this:

```
resources :books do
  resources :authors
end
```

So if I want to display the authors of a particular book, that's easy:

```
/books/1/authors
```

But what if I wanted to display the authors of all the books? I *want* something like this:

```
/books/all/authors

or:
/books/authors
```

Canonically, I assume it's just `/authors` but I'm curious if there's another way that's considered standard practice.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I want routes that look roughly like this:

```
/books/1/authors
/books/all/authors
```

So that the route doesn't look dramatically different for when I'm looking at authors for book 1 vs. all book authors, and I want to differentiate displaying authors outside of the context of books vs. with the context of books. So, simply having a `resources :authors` and a `AuthorsController#index` does not solve my question.

(Let's assume I don't want to have a `/views/authors/index.html` file)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have something like `/authors`
Then apart from your existing routes you can have a separate setup

### routes.rb

```
resources :books do
  resources :authors
end
resources :authors
```

### authors_controller.rb

```
def index
  @authors = Author.all # or Author.where(<CONDITIONS for search sort>)
end
```

And you can add respective views.
This will give you good control.

Further to follow DRY principle, you can create a partial as `authors/_index.html.haml` (or .erb) and reuse same for `/books/1/authors` i.e. authors of a particular book.

Edits:
If you do not want a separate controller, then you can distinguish on id param while finding authors collection.

```
# books/authors_controller.rb
def index
  @authors = params[:id] == 'all' ? Author.all : Book.find(params[:id]).authors
end
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In that case inside the index method of authors add this code @authors = Author.all

As simple as it is

Comment: That's missing the point of my question, I've added some clarifying remarks.